# High precision and low recall but with a balanced dataset

Tags: unbalanced-classes, precision, catboost

When i evaluated my model (CatBoost classifier), I noticed that my model has high precision and low recall (Recall: 0.59, Precision: 0.89) but the classes are perfectly balanced (1: 45.5, 2: 54.5) and I don't know how to handle this situation. What should I do?

Maybe these plots can help to understand the situation.
[image]
[image]

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you tried a grid search over hyper parameters?

Comment: No, not yet. Should I try hyp. tuning first?

Comment: Should be a good place to start.